# FindBugs gives error in Jenkins by a GWT project

Tags: gwt, jenkins, findbugs

I installed Jenkins as CI tool. I installed also the findbugs plugin to find potential bugs. (Also checkstyle, pmd, etc.).
My Project is a gwt-project using maven structure. 
I wrote the goals in jenkins configuration page to execute findbugs.

```
clean package findbugs:findbugs
```

But I am getting the following error and dont get any result from findbugs. The other plugins are working properly.

```
[INFO] Fork Value is true 
    [java] The following classes needed for analysis were missing: 
    [java]   com.google.gwt.core.client.GWTBridge 
    [java] Missing classes: 2  
[INFO] xmlOutput is false
```

What is the difference of FindBugs? What should I change?

Comment: Try adding gwt-dev.jar to classpath. This might be related to recent cleanup attempts with GWT 2.5 https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/JQCU4mQWNX0

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the upcomping gwt-2.5.1 release and the patch is here http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1722803.

Workaround - adding gwt-dev to the classpath - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/JQCU4mQWNX0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

That removed that GWTBridge warning for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because findbugs sees the GWT sources in the JARs. We've worked around this using `<onlyAnalyze>com.mycompany.</onlyAnalyze>` in the findbugs-maven-plugin configuration.

Comment: it's not in Jenkins, it's in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I changed the pom like that. But no effect   `code`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
     <onlyAnalyze>de.company.</onlyAnalyze>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>